# ranger "set preview_files true" does not work

Tags: file-manager, ranger

Since quite some time the file-preview-window in ranger stays empty.
I.e. it indeed shows up but does not preview the content of text-files.
Image preview and `.pdf` preview however does work.

The content of my ranger-config-file looks like the following:

```
user@computer ~ $ cat ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf
map DD shell mv %s /home/${USER}/.local/share/Trash/files/
# set colorscheme [default|jungle|snow|solarized]
set colorscheme default
set mouse_enabled false
set preview_images true
set preview_files true
```

**Solution attempt 1:**
I even explicitly inserted the line `set preview_files true` into `rc.conf`, all tough according to [this site](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/883f73/preview_files_in_ranger/dwi2fba), ranger should preview text-file-contents by default.

**Solution attempt 2:**
According to [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ranger#PDF_file_preview) the function in order to preview PDFs and images is stored in `~/.config/ranger/scope.sh`, so I did some research and figured out by [this side](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/883f73/preview_files_in_ranger/dwi1xe4), that `scope.sh` is the script ranger runs when it tries to preview **any** file. I never changed it knowingly, but to be save i did reset it:

```
user@computer ~ $ rm ~/.config/ranger/scope.sh 
user@computer ~ $ ranger --copy-config=scope
```

Still the preview stays empty!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution:
I just edited in `~/.config/ranger/scope.sh` the `case "$extension" in`-statement, by adding a new case called `txt` and every time when ranger finds a file with this extension it shall concatenate (`cat`) this file of given `$path` variable to `stdout`, therefore the preview window works again as expected:

```
case "$extension" in
    txt)
        cat "$path"
```